# Measuing CPU clock speed

Tags: c++, performance, microbenchmark, cpu-speed, cpu-cycles

I am trying to measure the speed of the CPU.I am not sure how much my method is accurate. Basicly, I tried an empty `for` loop with values like `UINT_MAX` but the program terminated quickly so I tried UINT_MAX * 3 and so on...

Then I realized that the compiler is optimizing away the loop, so I added a `volatile` variable to prevent optimization. The following program takes 1.5 seconds approximately to finish. I want to know how accurate is this algorithm for measuring the clock speed. Also,how do I know how many core's are being involved in the process?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    volatile int v_obj = 0;
    unsigned long A, B = 0, C = UINT32_MAX;

    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();

    for (A = 0; A < C; A++) {
        (void)v_obj;
    }
    t2 = clock();
    std::cout << (double)(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

    double t = (double)(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    unsigned long clock_speed = (unsigned long)(C / t);

    std::cout << "Clock speed : " << clock_speed << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As modern CPUs have variable clock  speed and multiple cores; running this sort of test will only measure the maximum clock speed of 1 core.

Comment: By putting `volatile` in there, you slowed your loop down to memory speed, defeating your goal of measuring CPU speed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So how exactly do you prevent optimization ?

Comment: @layzak This whole method of measuring CPU clock speed doesn't make sense. Don't fix it, throw it away.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Not *RAM* speed, just requiring a load in the asm.  It can hit in cache.  If compiled with optimization enabled, I'd expect this to run at 1 iteration per cycle on some modern x86 CPUs (2 or 3 uops in the loop, 1 load + 1 sub-and-branch https://godbolt.org/z/P7Ez5dMxs), but maybe not depending on quirks of code alignment (e.g. Skylake JCC erratum, or split across uop cache lines with the loop buffer disabled by microcode updates), or a narrow pipeline like Bulldozer-family.  You have no way of being sure, so yeah, not a good approach without knowing what uarch you target.

Comment: Also, a compiler could unroll this, and in fact clang does: https://godbolt.org/z/88Grvs9Y6 unrolls by 5. So the bottleneck on a modern x86 would be 2 or 3 loads per clock cycle.  (3 since Alder Lake.)  So yes, this loop can at best run at the speed of access to the same location repeatedly in the memory hierarchy, i.e. to L1d cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't measure clock speed at all, it measures how many loop iterations can be done per second. There's no rule that says one iteration will run per clock cycle. It *may* be the case, and you may have actually found it to be the case - certainly with optimized code and a reasonable CPU, a useless loop shouldn't run much slower than that. It could run at half speed though, some processors are not able to retire more than 1 taken branch every 2 cycles. And on esoteric targets, all bets are off.

So no, this doesn't measure clock cycles, except accidentally. In general it's extremely hard to get an empirical clock speed (you can ask your OS what it thinks the maximum clock speed and current clock speed are, see below), because

1. If you measure how much wall clock time a loop takes, you must know (at least approximately) the number of cycles per iteration. That's a bad enough problem in assembly, requiring fairly detailed knowledge of the expected microarchitectures (maybe a long chain of dependent instructions that each could only reasonably take 1 cycle, like `add eax, 1`? a long enough chain that differences in the test/branch throughput become small enough to ignore), so obviously anything you do there is not portable and will have assumptions built into it may become false (actually there is an other answer on SO that does this and assumes that `addps` has a latency of 3, which it doesn't anymore on Skylake, and didn't have on old AMDs). In C? Give up now. The compiler might be rolling some random code generator, and relying on it to be reasonable is like doing the same with a bear. Guessing the number of cycles per iteration of *code you neither control nor even know* is just folly. If it's just on your own machine you can check the code, but then you could just check the clock speed manually too so..
2. If you measure the number of clock cycles elapsed in a given amount of wall clock time.. but this is tricky. Because `rdtsc` doesn't measure clock cycles (not anymore), and nothing else gets any closer. You can measure *something*, but with frequency scaling and turbo, it generally won't be actual clock cycles. You can get *actual* clock cycles from a performance counter, but you can't do that from user mode. Obviously any way you try to do this is not portable, because you can't portably ask for the number of elapsed clock cycles.

So if you're doing this for actual information and not just to mess around, you should probably just ask the OS. For Windows, query WMI for CurrentClockSpeed or MaxClockSpeed, whichever one you want. On Linux there's stuff in `/proc/cpuinfo`. Still not portable, but then, no solution is.

As for

> how do I know how many core's are being involved in the process?

1. Of course your thread may migrate between cores, but since you only have one thread, it's on only one core at any time.

Comment: On linux there is `perf stat ./program` command, which will monitor and report mean cpu clock speed for any program "./program" (as X.XX GHz). It uses Hardware PMU - performance counters to count real cpu cycles (not tsc) used to run the program and it also does time accounting (task-clock software event). The real clock counters may be accessible with `perf_events` linux API or with some portable lib like PAPI directly from user-space.

Answer (score 0):

A good optimizer may remove the loop, since

```
for (A = 0; A < C; A++) {
    (void)v_obj;
}
```

has the same effect on the program state as;

```
A = C;
```

So the optimizer is entirely free to unwind your loop.

So you cannot measure CPU speed this way as it depends on the compiler as much as it does on the computer (not to mention the variable clock speed and multicore architecture already mentioned)

Comment: Doesn't the `volatile` scare the compiler into submission somewhat? E: apparently not

Comment: It can't *remove* the loop, unless it decides that `(void)v_obj`  doesn't count as a volatile access.  It can unroll the loop, though, as long as it still does the volatile load as many times as the C abstract machine.  In fact clang does: https://godbolt.org/z/88Grvs9Y6 unrolls by 5. So the bottleneck on a modern x86 would be 2 (or 3 since Alder Lake) loads per clock cycle  https://uops.info/, rather than bottlenecking on loop overhead (of 1 sub/jnz per clock, or worse if you're unlucky with Skylake's JCC erratum or code split across cache lines).